# A function is Borel iff $f^{-1}(a,\infty) \in \mathcal{F}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm reading Shao's *Mathematical Statistics* and part of a proposition is that, if $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ is a measurable space then:  A function $f$ is Borel iff $f^{-1}(a,\infty)\in \mathcal{F}$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$.  The definition of a function being Borel is that that it is measurable and the codomain is $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$.  Measurable is defined as the inverse image of every measurable set being measurable.  I see other questions in this community similar to mine, but the statement of the the theorem they talk about isn't quite so hazily expressed.

I think some of my confusion might come from the lack of fully stated assumptions here, but even at that I think the $\Rightarrow$ direction is easy.  If $f$ is Borel then $(a,\infty)\in \mathcal{B}$ from commonly known facts about Borel measurable spaces and from the fact that $f$ is assumed measurable then $f^{-1}(a,\infty)\in \mathcal{F}$.

The converse is what gets me.  If we assume only that $f^{-1}(a,\infty)\in \mathcal{F}$ but not that $f$ is measurable or anything else then it seems to me the result doesn't follow.  Maybe I'm supposed to assume throughout the proposition that $f$ is measurable.  Even still, I need to show that the codomain is $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$.  I suppose by definition of the assumption, its sample space contains all intervals and so all real numbers.  Perhaps for some reason I should assume it contains no more than that.  By a similar justfication I could take the assumption to be that the codomain contains all intervals $(a,\infty)$.  I definitely need to prove that it contains no more sets than that, but it seems to me it can--what if the codomain is the power set of $\mathbb{R}$, for instance?

Comment: if you have for $f:\mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb R$ for all $a\in R$ that $f^{-1}(a,\infty)\in \mathcal{F}$ then the function is measurable (I suppose that $\mathcal{F}$ is the Borel-sigma-algebra), and the co-domain are the reals of course

Comment: Well although it's not specified in the statement, up to this point in the text Shao has seemed to leave room for lots of options about what the domain space is, so I don't think we can assume the function domain is $\mathbb{R}$.  I guess we could assume codomain $\mathbb{R}$ from the context, although I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: If the codomain isn't $\mathbb{R}$ then it's not entirely clear what is meant by $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$.

Comment: @carmichael561 It's just the subset of $\Omega$ that maps into $(a,\infty)$.  $\Omega$ is any sample space.

Comment: what I said above also holds for a more general measurable space $(X,\mathcal A)$ where $X \not\subset \mathbb R$, i.e. for the mapping $f:(X,\mathcal A)\mapsto (\mathbb R, \mathcal B)$

Comment: @Addem: and if the codomain isn't $\mathbb{R}$, then how can $f$ map into $(a,\infty)\subset \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @carmichael561 Right, I'm guessing that's how I'm supposed to infer that the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$.  Still we can't say what $\Omega$ the domain is, and still $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ makes sense.

Comment: I agree that the wording is sloppy. Surely what is meant is: "A function $f : (X, \mathcal A) \to (\mathbb R, \mathcal B)$ is Borel measurable if and only if $f^{-1}(a, \infty) \in \mathcal A$ for every $a \in \mathbb R$."

Comment: I'm trending to agree that the wording is what has confused me. So far the book has been good but I'm starting to wonder if I shouldn't choose a different one.

Comment: @Addem If you're looking for an alternative, my favorite book on measure theory and integration is Cohn's [Measure Theory (2nd edition)](https://www.amazon.com/Measure-Theory-Birkhäuser-Advanced-Lehrbücher/dp/1461469554) It's very carefully written and I have never encountered any of the sort of sloppiness/ambiguity that you are seeing with your book.

Comment: @Bungo I'm really in the market for a Mathematical Statistics book, which I'm only reading in order to be able to read Greene's Econometrics and Gibbon's Non-Parametric Statistics.

Answer (score 1):

The key is that $f^{-1}$ commutes with the set operations.  Specifically:

If the set $f^{-1}(a, \infty)$ is in ${\cal F}$, then so is its complement: $f^{-1}(-\infty, a]$.  If this is true for all $a$, then, noting that
$$
(-\infty, a) = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(-\infty, a-{1 \over n}\right),
$$
we also have
$$
f^{-1}(-\infty, a) = 
\left[ \;
\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} f^{-1}\left(-\infty, a-{1 \over n}\right) 
\; \right]
\in {\cal F}.
$$

Therefore, $f^{-1}(a, b)$ also lies in ${\cal F}$, because
$$
(a, b) = (a, \infty) \cap (-\infty, b). 
$$

We have shown that $f^{1}$ of every open set is Borel.   Since the Borel algebra is generated by the open sets, it follows that $f$ is measurable.

The book (one and only) I would recommend on this is Vulikh's "Brief Course on the Theory of Functions".

Comment: To be measurable is to have all inverse images of measurable sets be measurable. How do I know which sets are measurable in the codomain when I'm not told what the codomain is and which measure is being used?  If I don't know which are measurable, how can either $f^{-1}(a,\infty), f^{-1}(a,b)\in \mathcal{F}$ be useful?  Most of the problems I'm encountering stem from this ambiguity.  It seems to me the most I could reasonably assume is that the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$.  If I'm supposed to assume that the codomain's space is $\mathcal{B}$ this seems like a very badly written proposition.

Comment: To put it a little differently, how do I know $(a,\infty)$ is measurable in the codomain space, and how do I know $\{1,2\}\cup (10,20)$ isn't?

Comment: We are told that the co-domain is the real line, and the symbol ${\cal B}$ usually refers to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.  Not sure why you see this as a bad proposition, because it answers the rest of your questions.:)  This $\sigma$-algebra is, by definition, generated from the open sets by the operations of complement, countable union, and countable intersection.

Therefore, in particular, all of the sets you listed are Borel sets.:)
$$\{a\} = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \; (a - 1/n, \; a + 1/n),$$
$$\{1, 2\} = \{1\} \cup \{2\},$$
and the set $(10, 20)$ is open, hence Borel.

Comment: But we are never told that the space of the codomain is $\cal B$. For all we know it could be the power set of the reals.

Comment: Well, "measurable function" has a meaning only if a $\sigma$-algebra of sets is specified in the co-domain as well as in the domain.  If it is left unspecified, they have not given you enough information to solve the problem.  But, since the book is about statistics, I am guessing that they mean Borel and that they are tacit about it because they probably don't work with other $\sigma$-algebras, as Borel is the most practical for the applications.

Comment: Did they perhaps say something like ``For the rest of this chapter, by measurable subsets of the real line we mean the Borel sets" earlier in the book?

Comment: Yeah, I wondered the same thing so I looked through the earlier parts of the book to see if they said anything like that, but they didn't.  I'm guessing they meant for the codomain to be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra too, but the stuff just before it kind of makes it seem like it doesn't have to be.  That's why I'm thinking it's a poorly worded proposition.